# How do I send data to Smart Contract via Ethers?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am able to deposit amount of Ether into my smart contract via the `depositFunds` function like below:

```
async function depositFunds() {
  console.log(`Depositing Funds...`);
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
    const transactionResponse = await contract.depositFunds({
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1"),
    });
  }
}
```

I am now trying to withdraw a portion of the funds (i.e. not all of them), but I cannot figure out how to pass the data to the `withdrawFunds` function of my contract.

```
async function withdrawFunds() {
  console.log(`Withdrawing Funds...`);
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
    const transactionResponse = await contract.withdrawFunds({
      data: "0.5",
    });
  }
}
```

Below is the ABI for my `withdrawFunds` function:

```
{
    inputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "_weiToWithdraw",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    name: "withdrawFunds",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  }
```

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: From what platform you are trying to interact with the contract?

Comment: Hi. Trying to use ethers.js to interact with a contract that is on Rinkeby testnet. Using VS code.

Comment: I see, I'm not a js guy so it's hard for me to help you there but if you want to test the functionality of your contract you can simply use myetherwallet to do it. I'm useing c# and Nethereum to interact with contracts through code but i dont know how to help with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await contract.depositFunds({
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1"),
});
```

This snippet builds the transaction object in a way that already contains the `depositFunds()` function selector at the beginning of the `data` field, followed by 0 arguments.

The object containing the `value` property is called the [overrides](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#contract-functionsSend) parameter. It allows you to override some other fields of the transaction, such as its `value`. It does not allow you to override the `data` field, as that's already build from the function name and arguments.

The [parseEther()](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/display-logic/#utils-parseEther) function converts an amount of ETH into its corresponding wei amount. In your case, that's `1000000000000000000` wei. So the actual `value` that you're sending with the transaction is this "1 and 18 zeros".

---

The `withdrawFunds(uint256)` function accepts the number of wei, that you want to withdraw, as an argument. So you need to convert the "0.5 ether" to the amount of wei, and simply pass it as the function argument.

```
const transactionResponse = await contract.withdrawFunds(
  // the function argument
  // note that it's not wrapped in curly brackets
  ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5")
);
```

You can also optionally specify some overrides, but it's not needed in this case.

```
const transactionResponse = await contract.withdrawFunds(
  ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5"),
  {
    // this is the `overrides` object after all function arguments
    gasPrice: "1000000000" // 1 billion wei == 1 Gwei
  }
);
```